# Javascript | Cómo tomar el dato del "selected"

Tags: javascript

En vez de tomar el dato de la "selected", toma todas las opciones. ¿Cómo sería para tomar únicamente el "OK" en este caso?
Gracias de antemano.

**Código:**

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatus_preventive").innerHTML;
print(x);
</script>
```

**Devuelve todo lo siguiente en vez de únicamente "OK":**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `innerHTML` te devuelve el contenido del control, si lo que deseas es averiguar el valor seleccionado debes acudir a la propiedad `value`

En tu caso sería

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatus_preventive").value;
print(x);
</script>
```

Y el resultado: 1

Si lo que deseas es capturar el texto de la opción:

```
<script>
var elem = document.getElementById("autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatus_preventive");
var x = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].text;
print(x);
</script>
```

Y el resultado: OK

Comment: Muy amable. Muchas gracias.